# How to wait until one line of code finishes before beginning the next in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to execute these two lines of code.

```
 reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
 reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetValueAsync(email);
```

It updates to a Firebase database, and creates write conflicts when adding multiple entries at the same time. I'm aware that Async naturally executes the line line of code while the first updates, but I don't know of any similar commands to replace this.

The Firebase documentation has examples using dictionary objects and transactions, but I haven't succeeding in writing to the database using those methods, and it took me a week to figure out the correct syntax since I'm very new to programming. Could anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: You need to `await` both of the asynchronous operations.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using unity and as far as I could find it doesn't support the await function.

Comment: Or rather, I can't use it in Unity while also using Firebase, as Firebase doesn't support over .Net 3.5, but await/async requires .Net 4+. Actually that may be Firestore, not Firebase. I'll look into it and see if I can do that, thank you.

Comment: You can try `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, but I'm not sure if that has a potential to cause deadlocks in unity.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
 await reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
 await reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetValueAsync(email);
```

The key is the **await** before the asynchronous method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using unity and as far as I could find it doesn't support the await function.

Comment: Or rather, I can't use it in Unity while also using Firebase, as Firebase doesn't support over .Net 3.5, but await/async requires .Net 4+. Actually that may be Firestore, not Firebase. I'll look into it and see if I can do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jonathon Chase said, you have to do something like this:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    await reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
    await reference.Child("users").Child(userId).SetValueAsync(email);
}
```